# input mismatch exception: scanning a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am writing a method that takes in a line from a file, and then is supposed to print the number from that file

```
public static void getScore(String line){
    Scanner lineScanner=new Scanner(line);
    lineScanner.next();
    int score=0;
    score= lineScanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println(score);
}
```

up in the main method I am just calling it with the string as a parameter, but no matter what I change, I get the error java.util.InputMismatchException. How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the line that you provide as input to this method? It sounds like you are trying to read an integer, but you have some text that can't be parsed as an integer.

Comment: hi matt, the file has both strings and integers, but if that is the case how can I "make" the scanner read the integers as they are?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the file contents?

Comment: Memorial Northwest             70593 San Marino                  77043

Answer (score 0):

You are calling in a string and trying to read an int causing your input mismatch, For example, an application expects to read integers from an input file, but instead, a real number is read. In this case, we have an input mismatch so then inputwillmismatch will be thrown

Answer (score 0):

If this is your input:

```
Memorial Northwest 70593 San Marino 77043
```

Your code is not correct.

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for `Scanner`:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

You create a scanner and then call `next` which returns the current token `Memorial` and advances to the next token.

You call `nextInt` which attempts to parse the current token `Northwest` as an integer, but it is not, so it throws `InputMismatchException`.

You would have to call `next` again to advance to the token that is actually an integer .